# adjusting css with a site using smarty php

Tags: php, html, css, smarty

I am trying to adjust some boxes on a site using smarty.

three sections populate data to the boxes all three sections share the same class. I am trying to figure out where to go to add a new classes or remove them if necessary but this is gibberish to me.

If someone can make sense of this I would appreciate it.

this file seems to be calling all the classes that makes sense to me. Now how to change them beats me. 
classifieds.tpl

```
{if count($from)}
<div class="classifieds">
<div class="list">
{foreach from=$from item=item key=key name=tmp}
{if $item.featured}<div class="featured">{/if}
<div class="listItemDiv">
    <div class="listRowDiv">
        {if $item.photo}<div class="image">
            <div class="photo-photo">
                <div>
                    {html_image file="$url/photos/`$item.photo`"}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>{/if}
        <div class="title"><a href="{$item.link}">{$item.title}</a></div>
        <div class="description">{$item.description}</div>
            {include file="$theme_template_root/items/actions.tpl"}
    </div>
</div>
{if $item.featured}</div>{/if}
{/foreach}
</div></div>

{else}
<div class="centerText">{$language.nothing_found}</div>
{/if}
```

This file seems to add the heading of each section but then call a function? maybe? To populate the box with the correct data?

```
<div class="columnSmall">

    {if $tip_message}

        {include file="boxes/tip.tpl" tip=$tip_message}

    {/if}

    {include file="boxes/greyTop/open.tpl" secheader=$language.quick_search}

    <div class="quickSearchForm">{include file="forms/simple.tpl" form="classifieds_qsearch"}</div>

    {include file="boxes/greyTop/close.tpl"}



    {if $banners.3}

    <div class="banner-side">{banner area="3"}</div>

    {/if}



</div>



<div class="columnWide">



    {include file="boxes/white/open.tpl"}



    <h2>{$language.featured_classifieds}</h2>

    {include file="lists/classifieds.tpl" from=$featured.cards}



    <h2>{$language.popular_classifieds}</h2>

    {include file="lists/classifieds.tpl" from=$popular.cards}



    <h2>{$language.new_classifieds}</h2>

    {include file="lists/classifieds.tpl" from=$new_classifieds.cards}



    {include file="boxes/white/close.tpl"}



</div>
```

Comment: I'm lost, what is the problem? Can't you just edit the tpl as you would do with a regular html file, adding classes as needed?

Comment: well the problem is that all of the php in the other file is being included with the same tpl file.. In order to get around this without having to rewrite everything I just made 3 separate files and changed the include path for each sections html and css.